# How to do use multiple .joins in an activerecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating json output and I'm basically getting a bunch of tasks, but I want the json output for each task to include the user's name.

How can I write an efficient activerecord query to get this?

Something like this: `Task.joins(:user).joins(:user_details)`

DB tables:

```
Task
|id|user_id|

User
|id|

UserDetails
|id|user_id|first_name|last_name|
```

Models:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user_details, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :tasks
end

class UserDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**EDIT**

`Task.joins(:user => :user_details)` does not contain `user_details.first_name` and `user_details.last_name` in the result set. That's what i'm ultimately after.

`[#<Task id: 5, user_id: 1>, #<Task id: 10, user_id: 3>, #<Task id: 9, user_id: 9>]`

Comment: Neither of your answer's cause an error, but they also don't get the first_name and last_name fields in the result set. See edit.

Comment: Sometimes creating a json 'view model' can simplify things, i like to use virtus https://github.com/solnic/virtus to create the model and map the active record attributes to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
Task.joins(user: :user_details)
```

Based on your edit, Rails doesn't work this way. You will still need to refer to the object itself to get its attributes unless you want to write custom SQL.

So, you can do this:

```
Task.joins(user: :user_details)
# Or
Task.includes(user: :user_details)
```

Then, in your view, you can refer to to the attribute via it's parent, which was grabbed in the query.

```
user.user_details.first_name
```

### But, There's a Better Way: Delegate

```
class User
  delegate :first_name, :whatever, to: :user_details
end
user.first_name => # Blah Blah
```

Read more about [delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).

Comment: So basically this is going to be a JSON api so I can't do user.user_details.first_name if it has to query the db for that. That's why I need it as part of `Task.joins...`

Comment: @Catfish Joins in the AR doesn't work the way you think it does. It doesn't return an object that has all the attributes from joined models (nor does include, although it can, in some instances). You need to parse the JSON independently, or delegate.

Comment: Ok I added `delegate :first_name, :last_name, :to => :user_details` to my User model, but in my controller `@tasks = Task.includes(:user => :user_details)` still does not have `first_name` and `last_name` in the result set.

Comment: You have to call those methods on the `user`, extracted from the task. `@task.user`. If you really want a flat JSON structure you have to create your own. As a rule of thumb, in Rails, unless you delegate, you will have to access dependent attributes through dependents. AR behaves like any other MVC ORM.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I guess I have to loop through the AR results and create a JSON object manually.